# System Identification 1-d altitude control

Tags: modeling, transfer-function

One dimensional altitude control of a hovercraft. The model's dynamic equations that I came up with are, I treat the hover craft as a rigid particle and my goal is to have it hover at or reach a certain desired height.

$$F = ma$$

$$X(t) - mg = ma$$

$$ma + mg = X(t)$$

Taking Laplace Transform yields

$$m \cdot s^2 \cdot Y(s)  - mg \cdot U(s) = X(s)$$

$$Y(s) = \frac{X(s)}{m \cdot s^2} + g \cdot U(s)$$

where **X** is the input thrust and **Y** is the output and **U(s)**  is a constant unit step. However I can not seem to isolate for $$Y(s)/X(s)$$. I think it may have something to do with me including the gravity force in the dynamics equation when it may act as a disturbance but I am not sure.

When creating a dynamic model of a system How do we handle the constant force of $$mg$$ do we treat it as a disturbance, and if so how do we go about doing that?

Comment: Watch the sign of $mg$ in the third equation.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are trying to derive the *transfer function* of the system, that is, the input/output relationship in the frequency domain for zero initial conditions.

$ G(s) = \frac{Y(s)}{R(s)}$

Where $G(s)$ is the transfer function, $Y(s)$ is the system output and $R(s)$ is the input to the system and can be a summation of any number of inputs.

$R(s) = R_1(s) + R_2(s) + ... + R_n(s)$

(Note: normally in systems and controls we use $U$ for inputs, but you have already defined it as a unit step at time = 0 in your question so I will avoid that notation and use $R$ instead.)

### How to treat the constant gravitational force

In a translational mass system, all external forces are inputs to the system. **The gravity is an external force and therefore must be included in your input term when you derive the transfer function.** Therefore you should have something like this:

$m\ddot{y} = x(t) + mg\dot{}u(t) = r_1(t) + r_2(t) = r(t)$

Taking the Laplace transform of both sides yields:

$ms^2Y(s) = X(s) + \frac{1}{s}mg$

$ms^2Y(s) = R_1(s) + R_2(s) = R(s)$

$G(s) = \frac{Y(s)}{R(s)} = \frac{1}{ms^2}$

### How to derive Y(s)/X(s)?

I am guessing you still want know how to derive the transfer function for $Y(s)/X(s)$. As you stated, it is not possible to separate out the $X(s)$ term, but you can instead define your input thrust as having a variable (controlled) component $x_c$ and a constant (operating point) component $x_{o}$.

$x(t) = x_c(t) + x_{o}\dot{}u(t)$

Then all you have to do is set your operating point to be equal to the gravitational force:

$x_{o} = -mg$

This then cancels with the gravitational force, allowing you to derive a transfer function between the variable component of your thrust and the altitude of the hovercraft.

$m\ddot{y} = x_c(t) - mg\dot{}u(t) + mg\dot{}u(t)$

$\frac{Y(s)}{X_c(s)} = \frac{1}{ms^2}$